# Is there a tool to visualize a tree search in ORtools?

Tags: or-tools, constraint-programming, graph-visualization

I am conceiving a global constraint with the ORtools solver, and to have a better understanding of my algorithm's behavior, i want to visualize the tree search generated by the solver.

So Is there any tool to visualize an ORtools tree search ?

Comment: which solver are you using?

Comment: I am using cpsolver

Comment: So sat search is not a tree search, and its behavior is too complex to describe, with a lot of potential delayed effects. What is your real question ?

Comment: I am not using the cp-sat solver, i am using the cp-solver. I am conceiving a global constraint on  cp-solver and i want to visualize  the tree search generated by the solver in order to understand some of my algorithm's behavior. And for this purpose i want to know if there is any tool to visualize the tree search generated by the cp-solver ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two c++ flags: cp_trace_search and cp_trace_propagation that will output very verbose logs on stderr.

I strongly recommend not using the original CP-Solver and encoding the constraint on CP-SAT.